# Download songs without password prompt

Tags: itunes, music, appletv

When using Apple TV, it asks me *every time* I want to download a song for my password. It happens each time I download from Apple TV (not my iPhone).

Is there a way to make it download the song without prompting for my password?

Answer (score 1):

- On your Apple TV, go to `Settings → Accounts → iTunes` and `App Store → Password Settings`.
- In the section labeled `Purchases And In-App Purchase`s choose the `Require Password` option.
- Now set your preferred level of protection to `Never`. You can also choose to be reminded to `Always enter password for purchases` or `After 15 Minutes`.
- Also select `Require Password` under the `Free Downloads` section and choose `Never` to turn off password prompts when downloading free apps from the App Store.

I'm assuming you have a 4th-gen Apple TV.